# What is the difference between two different type with same size in C?

Tags: c

If I run the following programs in two identical 64bit machines separately, and then compare their whole memory byte by byte, what difference I will see?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int x=1;
    getc(stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned long x=1;
    getc(stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

---

if the two x are not simple type, if they are two different name struct with same structure, same content and same size, what difference I will see?

---

OK, let me clarify the question, now the program changed to this

```
unsigned int x=1;
printf("%d",sizeof x);
return 0;
```

---

```
unsigned long x=1;
printf("%d",sizeof x);
return 0;
```

and two outputs are 4 for my compiler, and now the x is used, so no optimized

Now my question is, if you tell me there are some difference, where is the difference in memory? They should be different in somewhere of memory, because the types are different obviously. But where? I can't found it.

If you tell me there is no difference in memory. Why no difference. Something should be stored in somewhere of memory. Otherwise, I think the computer is no way to know that the address is a variable and what the variable is.

Comment: Note that it's common for a compiler on a 64-bit machine to still use 32-bit int.  But if they really are the same size, I doubt you'll see a difference.

Comment: Note also the msvc also has long at 32 bit for x64.

Comment: Note also that since `x` isn't used, that line will probably be optimized out so there will be no difference regardless of size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on compiler. Most 64bit compilers use 32bit `int` and 64bit `long`.

32bit compilers usually was 32bit `int` and 32bit `long`.

16bit compilers usually was 16bit `int`, 32bit `long` and 16bit `short`.

None of these is guaranteed unless specific compiler's documentation says so. Standard only says that `sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)`, and that `char` is 1 byte.

Comment: Please see my updated question, because I am not asking data type's difference

Comment: My answer still stands, update haven't changed core of question. In theory, it is up to compiler to differ these types whatever he wants. In practice you wouldn't see difference as long as sizeof is the same (which will change on different compilers). If you want to be sure - use `int32_t` ans so on data types introduced in C99 (stdint.h).